# Emacs, preview-latex, sseq

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview, sseq

I like using preview-latex in Emacs. I have been working a lot with spectral sequences lately and so I would like to get the figures I draw in `sseq` to show up in preview-latex. So far no luck. Does anybody have any ideas on how to make this work?

Currently the image does seem to compile but I just see a black box. No actual image appears.

Example for people to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{sseq}
\newcommand{\Zp}{Z_p}
\newcommand{\Zl}{Z_l}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{sseq}[entrysize=3.5cm,grid=dots]{0...3}{0...3}
    \ssmoveto 0 0
    \ssdrop{H_0(\Zp,H_0(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 0 1
    \ssdrop{H_0(\Zp,H_1(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 0 2
    \ssdrop{H_0(\Zp,H_2(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 0 3
    \ssdrop{H_0(\Zp,H_3(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 1 0
    \ssdrop{H_1(\Zp,H_0(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 1 1
    \ssdrop{H_1(\Zp,H_1(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 1 2
    \ssdrop{H_1(\Zp,H_2(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 1 3
    \ssdrop{H_1(\Zp,H_3(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 2 0
    \ssdrop{H_2(\Zp,H_0(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 2 1
    \ssdrop{H_2(\Zp,H_1(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 2 2
    \ssdrop{H_2(\Zp,H_2(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 2 3
    \ssdrop{H_2(\Zp,H_3(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 3 0
    \ssdrop{H_3(\Zp,H_0(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 3 1
    \ssdrop{H_3(\Zp,H_1(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 3 2
    \ssdrop{H_3(\Zp,H_2(\Zl^k))}
    \ssmoveto 3 3 
    \ssdrop{H_3(\Zp,H_3(\Zl^k))}
    \end{sseq}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [`preview-latex` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html):

> If you have a certain macro or environment that you want to preview,
>   first check if it can be chosen by cutomizing
>   `preview-default-options-list` in the `Preview Latex` group.
>
> If it is not available there, you can add it to
>   `preview-default-preamble` also in the `Preview Latex` group, by adding a
>   `\PreviewMacro` or `\PreviewEnvironment` entry (see [Provided commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html#Provided-commands))
>   *after* the `\RequirePackage` line.

So you have to add `sseq` to the list of environments to be preview.  You can customize the variable `preview-default-preamble` (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `preview-default-preamble` <kbd>RET</kbd>) or add the following code to your `.emacs`

```lisp
(eval-after-load "preview"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'preview-default-preamble
          "\\PreviewEnvironment{sseq}" t)))
```

> [image]

Comment: This does seem to work only when my background is white. When the background is black, I still don't see the diagram (though the other formulas do compile).

Comment: Can you post an example?  I'm not familiar with this package, I used an example provided in its manual.

Comment: @LalitJain if I compile the document you posted I see a white background.

Comment: Sorry, I meant emacs background color! However it does seem to work fine now. Thanks for your help!